# Any pythonic way to form dictionaries from dictionary where few keys have list values?

Tags: python-3.x

Example 1:

```
Items = {'key1': 1, 'key2': '[0,2,3,4]', 'key3': '[5,6,7,8]', 'key4': 9}
```

```
Expected output:

 {'key1':1, 'key2':2,'key3':0, 'key4':9}, {'key1':1, 'key2':0,'key3':5, 'key4':9}, ... ]
```

Since first value of list in key2 is 0, We will not proceed in that case.
Numbers of dictionaries generated should be 7.

Example 2:

```
Items = {'key1': 1, 'key2': '[0,2,0,0]', 'key3': '[5,6,7,8]', 'key4': 9}
```

```
Expected output:

 [{'key1':1, 'key2':2,'key3':0, 'key4':9}]
```

Only 1 dictionary will be create

Comment: Should the resulting output be a list of 4 dictionaries? Or a list of 16 dictionaries? Are the lists inside Items for sure going to be the same length?

Comment: Yeah.. first iteration I am trying to generate 4 lists. My final list should have 8 dictionaries like in each dictionary any one key2 or key3 should have value.

Comment: Still confusing. Can you add your full desired output?

Comment: [
    {'key1':1, 'key2':1,'key3':0, 'key4':9},
    {'key1':1, 'key2':0,'key3':5, 'key4':9},
    ...
] will have 8 elements

Comment: Please edit your question. Dont add a comment that is the same as what is in the question. That is useless. I don't know how you get 8 element with your given input and output. Please put the FULL expected output IN the question.

Comment: Also where did the `0` come from it what you pasted in the comment above?

Comment: Why does `key3` map to `0` in the output instead of the leftmost element taken from the list  `[5,6,7,8]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using for loops, where `n` refers to the length of the lists inside the Items dictionary:

```
Items = {'key1': 1, 'key2': [1,2,3,4], 'key3': [5,6,7,8], 'key4': 9}

out = []
n = 4
for i in range(n):
    d = {}
    for k in Items:
        if type(Items[k]) == int:
            d[k] = Items[k]
        elif type(Items[k]) == list:
            d[k] = Items[k][i]
    out.append(d)
print(out)
```

That code outputs the following:

```
[
    {'key2': 1, 'key3': 5, 'key1': 1, 'key4': 9},
    {'key2': 2, 'key3': 6, 'key1': 1, 'key4': 9},
    {'key2': 3, 'key3': 7, 'key1': 1, 'key4': 9},
    {'key2': 4, 'key3': 8, 'key1': 1, 'key4': 9}
]
```

Notice that I changed the values in the Items dict to be lists rather than string representations of lists.

Comment: Huh, my solution found list length dynamically but I could have just hard coded like you... Damn I did it the hard way :P. You can always use `ast.literal_eval` to turn the string representation of a list into a list. Or you can use `json.loads`. Though it is easier to fix the source that fix it down stream.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems bit close solution to my problem, The only problem here is what if list contains 'nan' values and how to discard dictionary if any of the values of 'key2' or 'key3' is 0.

Comment: Hi @Aarif1430 - if you have additional requirements, please edit them in to your original question so that any answers you get are more likely to be aligning with what you want, thanks!